# Flutter http get json data

Tags: json, flutter, http, dart

I am having difficulty with data get. I am very new to Flutter and although I read the articles, I could not overcome this problem. I was able to get the data individually, but I couldn't put it in a loop. The codes are below.

```
    Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
  var jsonData = await http.get("https://example.com/api/posts.php");
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonData.body);
  Match postList= Post.fromJsonMap(jsonResponse);
  return (jsonResponse as List)
      .map((postList) => Post.fromJsonMap(postList))
      .toList();
  //print("post" + postList.result[1].home);
}
```

When I run the print method, I can print the data. However, when I send it to futurebuilder, the data is not coming.

```
body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getPosts(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print("test");
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].result[index].home),
                      subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].result[index].title),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Text(
                            snapshot.data[index].result[index].id.toString()),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          }),
```

Note: The codes I used as an example: https://github.com/emrealtunbilek/flutter_json_http/blob/master/lib/remote_api.dart

Comment: Can you do this `print(snapshot.data)` in place of `print("test")` and let me know what you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try add additional if branch like this

```
} else if (snapshot.hasError) {
    print(snapshot.error);
} else {
```

Comment: The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<Match>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<Match>>#a36f2):
A build function returned null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonToDart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) for parse data and cast to your model

Comment: I created my model using Json to dart, but data is not coming. Is there a problem with JSON data? I can pull data from another source. (jsonplaceholder)

Comment: The JSON type I use is: {"success":true,"result":[{"id":"3970","home":"Test","title":"TestTitle"}],"premium":true,"type":null}

Comment: use jsonDecode(stringData); and pass it to model.fromJson();